# Is a good user experience to display actions on the top of the screen on the web?

Tags: gui-design, navigation, design-patterns

Navigation on the top of the screen is common on the web. To add actions like "Edit", "See details", "Copy" in the navbar is more specific on the desktop.
Fluent UI, Sharepoint added this pattern some years ago and personally I found it very useful for intranets, internal apps. I'm aware that some users just don't use Windows (I was a lot of time just a Mac user) and they are not familiar with this pattern.
What do you think, is a good user experience to display actions on the top of the screen on the web? Do you think it offers more clarity or is confusing?
To be more clear, let's take as an example a table. Do you think is a good UX to display the filters and actions on the top of the screen or at the head of the table is better?

[image]

Comment: do you mean on a web page? I'm not sure what you mean, I use both Windows and Mac and menus are up there, so I guess you mean something else. Do you have an example?

Comment: Yes, on a web page, and I ask for the website navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly that's quite an interesting question.

The answer for the question will be based on three points.

1. **End user POV / Past Experience**

Who is the end user and what are the apps they are exposed to, example as mentioned mac users and windows user & the app on which platform we are going to use and maintain similar, as our main focus is to reduce the cognitive load and time taken to learn new position and complete the task.

2. **Information Grouping**

As per the example provided the filters should be on head of the table as the filters are used to filter the data in the table will not be used as a the generic feature through out the every screens of application.

3. **Priority of User's Action**

Based on the user's most frequent action and priority what we want the user to focus on are displayed on the screen upfront instead of placing it under menu as it takes extra effort (increases the cost per click).

These are my Point of views..

Answer (score 0):

Actions and filters belong to the objects that they affect.

If you have a page with a large number of form fields and every field can be edited, it could make sense for an Edit button to "belong to the page" and place the page in an Edit mode.

[image: Wireframe of a form with 10 fields, one edit button]

If, on the other hand, you have multiple sections or cards with editable fields on them, the cards each likely represent a distinct user task, and it's better for the Edit action to belong to each card. That way the Update button is closer to the task and easier to find.

[image: A form with two editable cards]

The reason for this is [Fitts's Law](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/fitts-s-law-the-importance-of-size-and-distance-in-ui-design), which tells us that the distance that a user has to move their mouse affects their experience. When a user is editing something close to where their mouse is, they'd rather be able to apply actions without having to scroll up and down a page to find the controls.

If a table is the only thing on a page that can be edited, you still might want the Edit action to be in close proximity to the table itself, because it helps the user quickly understand what is being edited. Also, in the future, you might have a page with multiple editable tables, and having a consistent pattern is better than mixing them.